# Meaning of "Query results" and "Rendered output" in Views cache?

Tags: 7, views, caching

Previously I've set the "Query results" and "Rendered output" cache to 1 hour.

What I need is:

- Cache for 1 hour
- Update the cache immediately when related node updated

But when updating node, it takes exactly 1 hour for the views page to be updated.

I'm quite confuse about what is "Query results" and "Rendered output"?

Is "Query results" the `GET` request?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Query results” are raw data from DB. After fetching data you often do some additional work (modifications, templates) with data and then render it to HTML in some way — so you get a “Rendered output”. For more flexibility you have two levels for caching here.

As I think (*I can be wrong!*) here is no sense to set “Query results cache” time less than “Rendered output cache”.

Your use case, as I can see, to flush View cache immediately after new content added. You can solve it with additional staff [Cache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions), which requires Rules.
For example, you can create a rule with event `"After saving new content"` or `"After updating existing content"`, condition `"Content is published"` and one of the Cache actions.
[image]

Cache will be flushed regardless of cache settings in your view.